# How to filter stream of Page<E> by stream Java 11 API in Spring boot app

Tags: java, java-stream, filtering

I have the following method and data:-

```
public Page<MydataDTO> getData(){
    // here var data is Page<MydataDTO>
    var data = this.dataRepository.findAll(specification, pageable) 
                                        .map(MydataDTO::from);

   if(startOfDay != null && atEndOfDay != null){
        Instant finalStartOfDay = startOfDay;
        Instant finalAtEndOfDay = atEndOfDay;
   // here var filteredData is Lit<MydataDTO>       
   var filteredData = vv.stream().filter(e -> e.getCreated().isAfter(finalStartOfDay) && e.getCreated().isBefore(finalAtEndOfDay))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
}
```

As I have to return Page from this function. How can fitter data and return Page from this function? Can I  convert List to Page? Maybe yes, but for the performance reason, I shouldn't do it. Coz converting Page to List and again back to Page sounds crazy. For a large collections, it is very bad.  How can I do it efficiently way?

Comment: what class is `Page`? can you link the Javadoc to it? adding appropriate tags might help further.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html

Comment: Your comment that says, "here var data is Page<MydataDTO>" is very good hint that you should declare the variable type explicitly and not use type inference. Type inference is great when a human can easily see what the left-hand type is from the right-hand expression. E.g. I can easily see `filterData` is a `List`; I can't easily see what its generic type is.

Comment: What is `vv`? An [mcve] would be much more helpful to troubleshoot your problem and isolate it from unrelated details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already extended `JpaSpecificationExecutor<MydataDTO>` if not please extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

try building query dynamically and do the filtering via query instead of first fetching the result and then filtering

```
final Optional<Date> after = Optional.ofNullable(startOfDay);
final Optional<Date> before = Optional.ofNullable(atEndOfDay);

Specification<MydataDTO> inBetweenDates = null; 

if(before.isPresent() && after.isPresent()) {
    inBetweenDates = (root, query, cb) -> {
        return cb.between(root.get("created"), after.get(), before.get());
    };
}

dataRepository.findAll(inBetweenDates, pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to obtain the already filtered data by adding a filter by dates in your specification.
If you want to do it as you say you would have to create a new page with the filtered list.

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Test
public void test1() {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10,  Sort.by(Order.desc("id")));
    Page<User> page = userRepository.findAll(pageable);
    
    Page<User> pageWithFilteredData = new PageImpl<User>(page.stream().filter(user -> user.getName().contains("john"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()), page.getPageable(), page.getTotalElements());
}
```